# Enabling test coverage throws data binding error

Tags: android, android-databinding, test-coverage

I have a multi module android project. With `core` and `main` as modules.

I am using data binding on both the modules. But whenever I try to enable testCoverage on core module project build fails with error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Found data binding errors.
  Cannot find the setter for attribute 'app:marginStart' with parameter type int on android.widget.LinearLayout.
  file:///Users/abhimanyushegokar/droid/myproject/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/droid/core/unspecified/proj/res/layout/my.xml Line:25
```

Any help regarding this would be appreciated.